# Can you upload maps from QGIS to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, story-map

I am making a storymap in ArcGIS Online where I want to show some maps I made in QGIS.

It seems that you can only show maps that are in the ArcGIS Online gallery.

I tried making a map in ArcGIS Online very briefly, it is very limited and 
I can't make the same map unfortunately.

Is there a way to upload your maps from QGIS in my storymap from ArcGIS Online and make them interactive ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be making the map in ArcMap and then publishing to ArcGIS online? http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-publishing-a-map-service.htm ArcMap has many functions and options that are similar to QGIS so you should be able to get a very close approximation of your QGIS map.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that qgis is free and arcmap isn't. I would love to have it though, but I don't have the money for it since it is pretty expensive.

Comment: You've missed the whole point of the exercise. Story Maps are online maps, published with ArcGIS tools to an ArcGIS Server instance, and hosted either locally or in ArcGIS Online. The maps are not **uploaded**, they are **published** -- while the publishing tool isn't strictly required, you probably don't have a few months or years available to reverse-engineer the process.

Answer (score 5):

You can use OGIS Cloud to publish the service as WMS or WMTS as per your requirement.

URL: https://qgiscloud.com/

And then add OGC services in the Webmap the is being used by your story map in ArcGIS online.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/ogc.htm

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

ArcGIS Pro will offer a much more integrated experience in being able to create an entire Web Map (data, cartography, popups, bookmarks, etc.) and easily share and replicate that to ArcGIS Online.

However, if you have QGIS, you can still take the results of your work and export it into [a format](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-items.htm) that is supported for publishing from the browser in ArcGIS Online.  So, you could export your results to shapefile, upload them to your content in ArcGIS Online, publish as hosted feature layers, and then you have a lot of control for symbology and analysis from within the Map Viewer to create your own web maps and then embed in whatever web application takes your fancy.

In theory, someone could develop a plugin for QGIS that could automate some of this, as there is an Admin API for ArcGIS Online.  But for now, you will have to take a manual process.